# Were &/ and &% removed from Swift language?

Tags: swift, swift2, operators

Have `&/` and `&%` been removed from Swift 2.0 or has the syntax changed?

The following appears to have worked in Swift 1.2:

```
var divByZero: Int8 = 100 &/ aZero
var remainderDivByZero: Int8 = 100 &% aZero
```

From the [learn-swift playground](https://github.com/nettlep/learn-swift/blob/master/23.%20Advanced%20Operators.playground/section-1.swift#L84-L85)

I've looked in the language guide [Advanced Operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID28) section and I don't see any reference to these operations.  I can't seem to find release notes from Apple with a detailed list of changes from 1.2 to 2.0.

Comment: It *is* listed in the Xcode 6.3 release notes: https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html: *"The &/ and &% operators were removed, to simplify the language and improve consistency."*

Comment: thanks, my error was not looking far enough back!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Revision history 2015-04-08](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/RevisionHistory.html) amongst others:

> - Updated for Swift 1.2.
> - Removed the overflow division (&/) and overflow remainder (&%) operators from [Overflow Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID37).

Seems to have worked until including `Swift 1.1`

The [release notes for Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-SW26) include

> The &/ and &% operators were removed, to simplify the language and improve consistency.
> Unlike the &+, &-, and &* operators, these operators did not provide two’s-complement arithmetic behavior; they provided special case behavior for division, remainder by zero, and Int.min/-1. These tests should be written explicitly in the code as comparisons if needed. (17926954).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to the revision history and release notes.  I hadn't realized the Swift language release notes would be part of the XCode release notes.  Too used to the part of the world where choice programming language doesn't determine the IDE... arguably not strictly true for Apple, but close enough.  Great, informative links!